# Search with only meta Key in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need help to make a query to customize the default wordpress searching. I don't want to include title or content or excerpt in wordpress searching but want to search based on meta value of that post.

In default wordpress search wordpress add meta query in "AND" Condition. If there is a way if meta query add in or condition it will also be fine.

Please Help

Comment: think, you first should look at [WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query). the default relation is `AND`, but you can change it with `OR`, `LIKE` and etc. if this is not your question, then, please, be more detailed and add some example, what you want to do

Comment: I know avout WP_Meta_Query it will set relation beteeen different meta key condition. but in search when you add meta query in default search query the query will look like where1=1 and (title like something or content like something or excerpt like somthing) and( multiple meta condition will pu here acccring to your array) I want these meta conditions with "or" relation to content, title ans excrept.

Comment: [look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49990065/8053001). is it what you want( only instead of `WP_User_Query`, you can use `WP_Query` )?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to changing the **main** query on search results pages (e.g. `http://example.com/?s=hello`), then try one of these options:

**Option #1**

This is for:

> I don't want to include title or content or excerpt in wordpress
>   searching

Hook to `pre_get_posts` and empty the `s` parameter.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $wp_query ){
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_search() ) {
        $wp_query->set( 's', '' );
    }
});
```

**Option #2**

This is for:

> In default wordpress search wordpress add meta query in "AND"
>   Condition. If there is a way if meta query add in or condition it will
>   also be fine.

Hook to `get_meta_sql` and substitute the `AND` with `OR`.

```
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql, $meta_query, $type, $primary_table ){
    global $wpdb;

    if (
        'post' === $type &&
        $wpdb->posts === $primary_table &&
        is_main_query() && is_search()
    ) {
        if ( $sql['where'] && ' AND (' === substr( $sql['where'], 0, 6 ) ) {
            $sql['where'] = ' OR ' . substr( $sql['where'], 5 );
        }
    }

    return $sql;
}, 10, 4 );
```

**Option #3**

Create a custom search page and use a custom `WP_Query` instance for querying the posts.

```
$q = new WP_Query([
    'meta_key'   => 'some_key',
    'meta_value' => 'some_value',
    // Or use meta_query
]);
```

**Options #1 and #2 are both tricky** and may conflict with plugins on your site, or any custom code which modifies the search-related parameters/queries. Or even standard queries. So use the code at your very own risks.

Hope that helps..

Comment: Option #3 basically doesn't modify the global `$wp_query` object. But I put that option in the list because if I were you, I'd probably go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I create a ajax from where I send the input text as "search_text" and check the text is feature or not from meta_key "job_is_featured" value which is store in postmeta. and also check  into custom post type category id.

```
     $catids = '22';
  $args = array(
'post_type' => 'job', 'order' => 'DESC','posts_per_page' => '-1','s' => 'search_text' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'job-category',
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $catids,
    ),
   ),
   'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'job_is_featured',
        'value'    => 1,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'job_is_featured',
        'value'    => 0,
        'compare' => '=',
    ),
),
    array(
        'key' => 'job_location',
        'value'    => 'search_text',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),

 );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: I think you are a little bit confused in my question let me explain you again,   a default wordpress search query search the cotnent from title, excerpt and content with or condition like (where title like keyword or excerpt like keyword or content like keyword ) after then when you add some more parameter like meta  it will in and condition like (where ( title like keyword or excerpt like keyword or content like keyword ) **AND** (meta like keyword  or meta like keyword )) i want to change this and to **OR**

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code which you need to add in functions.php**

This code will work with Post Meta and Taxonomy both

```
if(!function_exists('custom_wp_meta_and_tax_search')){
    function custom_wp_meta_and_tax_search($search_args){

        /* taxonomy query and meta query arrays */
        $tax_query = array();
        $meta_query = array();

        /* Keyword Based Search */
        if( isset ( $_GET['keyword'] ) ) {
            $keyword = trim( $_GET['keyword'] );
            if ( ! empty( $keyword ) ) {
                $search_args['s'] = $keyword;
            }
        }

        /* Custom Meta Key Parameter */ 
        if( isset($_GET['meta_input']) && ($_GET['meta_input'] != 'any')){
            $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'custom_meta_key',
                'value' => $_GET['meta_input'],
                'compare' => 'like',                    
            );
        }

        $min_value = '';
        $max_value = '';
        if(isset($_GET['min-value']) && $_GET['min-value'] <> 'any'){
            $min_value = $_GET['min-value'];
        }

        if(isset($_GET['max-value']) && $_GET['max-value'] <> 'any'){
            $max_value = $_GET['max-value'];
        }
        /* Logic for Min and Max value Parameters */
        /* You need to replace custom_tax with custom taxonomy */
        if( isset($min_value) && ($min_value != 'any') && isset($max_value) && ($max_value != 'any') ){

            $min_value = doubleval($min_value);
            $max_value = doubleval($max_value);
            if( $min_value >= 0 && $max_value > $min_value ){
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => 'custom_tax',
                    'value' => array( $min_value, $max_value ),
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                );
            }
        }else if( isset($min_value) && ($min_value != 'any') ){
            $min_value = doubleval($min_value);
            if( $min_value > 0 ){
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => 'custom_tax',
                    'value' => $min_value,
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => '>='
                );
            }
        }else if( isset($max_value) && ($max_value != 'any') ){
            $max_value = doubleval($max_value);
            if( $max_value > 0 ){
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => 'custom_tax',
                    'value' => $max_value,
                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => '<='
                );
            }
        }

        // /* if more than one taxonomies exist then specify the relation */
        $tax_count = count( $tax_query );
        if( $tax_count > 1 ){
            $tax_query['relation'] = 'AND';
        }

        /* if more than one meta query elements exist then specify the relation */
        $meta_count = count( $meta_query );
        if( $meta_count > 1 ){
            $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
        }

        if( $tax_count > 0 ){
            $search_args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
        }

        /* if meta query has some values then add it to base home page query */
        $search_args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;


        /* Sort By meta value */
        /* You need to replace "custom_meta_key" with the key of custom field you created with post. */
        if( (isset($min_value) && ($min_value != 'any')) || ( isset($max_value) && ($max_value != 'any') ) ){
            $search_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $search_args['meta_key'] = 'custom_meta_key';
            $search_args['order'] = 'ASC';
        }



        return $search_args;
    }
}
add_filter('custom_search_parameters','custom_wp_meta_and_tax_search');
```

**Now Run the Query and Filter your posts with Post Meta and taxonomy**

```
$custom_search_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => $paged,  
);
$custom_search_args = apply_filters('custom_search_parameters',$custom_search_args);
$search_query = new WP_Query( $custom_search_args );
```

Answer (score 0):

## Add this in function.php

```
                add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $q )
                {
                if( $title = $q->get( '_meta_or_title' ) )
                {
                add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', function( $sql ) use ( $title )
                {
                global $wpdb;

                // Only run once:
                static $nr = 0; 
                if( 0 != $nr++ ) return $sql;

                // Modified WHERE
                $sql['where'] = sprintf(
                " AND ( %s OR %s ) ",
                $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title like '%%%s%%'", $title),
                mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
                );

                return $sql;
                });
                }
                });
```

## Usage

```
                $meta_query = array();
                $args = array();
                $search_string = "test";

                $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'staff_name',
                'value' => $search_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                );
                $meta_query[] = array(
                'key' => 'staff_email',
                'value' => $search_string,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                );

                //if there is more than one meta query 'or' them
                if(count($meta_query) > 1) {
                $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
                }

                // The Query
                $args['post_type'] = "staff";
                $args['_meta_or_title'] = $search_string; //not using 's' anymore
                $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;



                $the_query = new WP_Query($args)
```

Answer (score 0):

if ( $query->is_search())
{

```
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

//print_r($meta_query);
$meta_query[] = array('key'       => '_product_attributes', /* Product Attribute Meta key Here example (_sku, _stock, _stock_status, height, width ) */
    'value'     => $city,
    'compare'   => 'LIKE');
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

}

}

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query' , 'Add_custom_search2' );